# Date time picker with milliseconds

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datepicker

Is there any way I can get milliseconds in bootstrap . I am using DB2 time stamp for inserting the date time. So while performing the search I need to allow the user to select date and time with milliseconds also. I tried using the link (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) but I was not able to get the slider. Can anyone help me with how to order the required js and css files. Or is there anyway I can get datetimepicker with the format e.g 2016-12-11 02:22:22.444444(6 digits). This is the order I have included files.

```
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-timepicker-1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js">/script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular-1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-datepicker-master/bootstrap-datepicker-master/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jsfiles/scriptfile1.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/jquery-timepicker-1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/datatables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/angular-datatables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap-datepicker-master/bootstrap-datepicker-master/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="/controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to bring up the time picker or need to order the lib files in HTML, can you make it clear what you need

Comment: With this order I am able to bring up the date picker but time selector is not coming. May be checking the order will help.

Comment: I don't think so by ordering your lib files will bring you the timepicker, have you added this
$('#basic_example_4').timepicker(
 $.timepicker.regional['es']
);  
to your script file

Comment: it would be better if you create a plunker link with your codes

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/sNa8d/#&togetherjs=rthkBA3NFG ) This is another link I came across. This is similar to what I want. But if I include the files in the order I have mentioned above I am not able to see the time picker.

Comment: you want time picker or datepicker or both

Comment: I want both time and date picker. I want in such a manner that user will be able to select date and time in this format 2016-12-11 02:22:22.123456.

Comment: create a plunkr of your code (don't need other links)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Check working demo [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/PbrVKe)

JS:

```
$('#basic_example_3').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss:l tt"
});
```

It will give you this

[image]

As per your requirement you need 6 digit for millisecond. But in background the JavaScript `getMilliseconds()` Method returns the milliseconds (from 0 to 999) of the specified date and time.

Even though if you force to set `getMilliseconds()` to 6 digit, it will be of no use as it returns `000999` because 1000 millisecond = 1 second.

You can try yourself by setting the milli second digit example [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime_millisec)

Comment: Note: Demo stopped working due to network issue from host library. `Now issue is fixed. Demo is working Now`